# PLS-00363: expression 'HTP.HTBUF_LEN' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I am getting a very strange error when trying to view this procedure via OWT on my browser.  I have other schemas connected via wdbsvr.app and all work perfectly.  This schema comes from a import we did on another machine.  Do I need to change something in the configuration of the OWT?

Thanks!

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PLS-00363: expression 'HTP.HTBUF_LEN' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 5, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CRS"."TEST1"  IS

BEGIN
  HTP.HTMLOPEN;                            -- generates <HTML>
  HTP.HEADOPEN;                            -- generates <HEAD>
  HTP.TITLE('Title');                      -- generates <TITLE>Hello</TITLE>
  HTP.HEADCLOSE;                           -- generates </HTML> 

  -- generates <BODY TEXT="#000000" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
  HTP.BODYOPEN( cattributes => 'TEXT="#000000" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"');

  -- generates <H1>Heading in the HTML File</H1>
  HTP.HEADER(1, 'Heading in the HTML File');

  HTP.PARA;                                 -- generates <P>        
  HTP.PRINT('Some text in the HTML file.'); 
  HTP.BODYCLOSE;                            -- generates </BODY>
  HTP.HTMLCLOSE;                            -- generates </HTML>

END;
```

Comment: Note...  I am trying this on mydomain.com/pls/schemaname/test1 and it gives the above error however I have created the exact same procedure with the exact same name and it works perfectly via mydomain.com/pls/other_schemaname/test1.  The wdbsvr.app is the exact same for both except for the passwords of course.

Comment: does the imported schema in which the error occurs contain a package named 'htp'?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what happened.  I assume the previous DBA added these packages into the schema since it was imported from a different version of Oracle. Once I removed the local htp packages everything worked perfectly with the system-wide htp.  Thank you!